# Remove all Alpha characters from a string until it reaches a numeral

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to remove all Alpha characters from a string in PHP until I reach a Numeric character. I have about 500 Addresses in a table and they contain information before them such as *Billing Address 321 test street* *Shipping Address 123 testing way* etc. Does anyone know if PHP has a function like this or know of a simple way of doing this using PHP?

Comment: You should consider only removing "Billing Address " and "Shipping Address " instead, so that you don't potentially mangle valid addresses.

Comment: those were just examples there is a variety of different strings prior to the actual address

Comment: You mean something like `$str = preg_replace('~^\D+~', "", $str);` ? Replace everything, that is not `\d` which is a shorthand to `[0-9]`. The upper `\D` is negation of `\d` so `+` one or more non-digits from start `^`

Comment: Your comment I feel is helpful in the case of it having specific rhetorical strings prior to the data I need. But in this case there are quite a few probably 50 or more different strings of before the address it is not consistent. Unless I am understanding you wrong

Comment: "... so that you don't potentially mangle valid addresses."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a regex like the following:

```
<?php
   $string = "Shipping Address 123 testing way";
   $pattern = '/^([^0-9])+/'; // non numeric values at the start of the string
   $replacement = '';
   echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

You can read up more on preg_replace [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)